# Migrating Jetty 6.1 to 9.3 has multiple issue

Tags: embedded-jetty

> Hi All need few suggestion while migrating our legacy application
>   which has in-built jetty server 6.1.
>
> I am trying to migrate to Jetty 9.3, yes after long gap and after
>   decided to move to JAVA 8. While changing few of the files I encounter
>   piece of code written in jetty 6.1.
>
> Code:

```
@Override
    public void initialize(final ServiceConfiguration genericConfig, final Controller controller, final int serviceId,
        final ServiceLock lock) throws Exception {
        if (genericConfig instanceof JettyServerConfiguration) {
            configuration = (JettyServerConfiguration) genericConfig;
        } else {
            configuration = XmlConfigurable.createInstance(JettyServerConfiguration.class,
                    genericConfig.getXmlConfigElement());
        }

        server = new Server();
        log.info("jetty version = " + Server.getVersion()); //frozen

        maxWaitForSlave = getConfiguration().getMaxWaitForSlave();

        final boolean debug = getConfiguration().getMortBayDebug();
        log.info("mortbay debug = '" + debug + "'"); //frozen
        org.mortbay.log.Log.getLog().setDebugEnabled(debug);

        // Configure http
        final boolean httpEnabled = getConfiguration().getHttpEnabled();

        if (httpEnabled) {
            // Setup http connector as nio or socket.
            final boolean nio = getConfiguration().getNioEnabled();
            Connector connector;

            if (nio) {
                connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
            } else {
                connector = new SocketConnector();
            }

            final int mainPort = getConfiguration().getHttpPort();

            log.info("adding default connector on port '" + mainPort + "'"); //frozen
            connector.setPort(mainPort);

            server.addConnector(connector);
        }

        // Configure SSL
        final boolean sslEnabled = getConfiguration().getSslEnabled();

        if (sslEnabled) {
            final int sslPort = getConfiguration().getSslPort();
            final String sslKeyStore = getConfiguration().getSslKeyStore();
            final String sslPassword = getConfiguration().getSslPassword();
            final String sslKeyPassword = getConfiguration().getSslKeyPassword();
            final String sslTrustPassword = getConfiguration().getSslTrustPassword();

            //final boolean nio = configuration.getBooleanValue("NioEnabled", false); //frozen
            //if(nio) {
            //sslConnector = new SslSelectChannelConnector();  available in jetty 7
            //} else {
            final SslSocketConnector sslConnector = new SslSocketConnector();
            sslConnector.setKeystore(sslKeyStore);
            sslConnector.setTruststore(sslKeyStore);
            sslConnector.setPassword(sslPassword);
            sslConnector.setKeyPassword(sslKeyPassword);
            sslConnector.setTrustPassword(sslTrustPassword);
            sslConnector.setPort(sslPort);
            log.info("adding ssl connector on port '" + sslPort + "'"); //frozen
            server.addConnector(sslConnector);

            //}
        }

        // Check we had 1 connector else the server is useless
        if (server.getConnectors().length == 0) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("No connectors registered.  Please see HttpEnable or SslEnable XML tags."); //frozen
        }

        // Configure the handlers
        final HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();

        for (final WebAppContext webAppContext : getConfiguration().getWebAppContexts()) {
            log.info("Adding WebAppContext " + webAppContext.getWar() + " at " + webAppContext.getContextPath()); //frozen
            handlers.addHandler(webAppContext);
        }

        // See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Logging+Requests
        final boolean accessLogEnabled = getConfiguration().getLogEnabled();

        if (accessLogEnabled) {
            final RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
            final File logDir = ServiceUtilities.getLogDirectory();

            if (!logDir.exists()) {
                logDir.mkdirs();
            }

            final File logFile = new File(getConfiguration().getLogFormat());

            if (!logFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
                logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }

            final NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog(getConfiguration().getLogFormat());
            requestLog.setRetainDays(getConfiguration().getLogRetain());
            requestLog.setAppend(getConfiguration().getLogAppend());
            requestLog.setExtended(getConfiguration().getLogExtended());
            requestLog.setLogTimeZone(getConfiguration().getLogTz());
            requestLog.setLogLatency(getConfiguration().getLogLatency());
            requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
            handlers.addHandler(requestLogHandler);
        }

        handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());

        server.setHandler(handlers);

        server.setUserRealms(new UserRealm[] { new OSMUserRealm() });

        JettyServerInfo.install(server);

        super.initialize(configuration, controller, serviceId, lock);
    }
```

> After the suggestion given below , I have re-written it like:

```
@Override
public void initialize(final ServiceConfiguration genericConfig, final Controller controller, final int serviceId,
    final ServiceLock lock) throws Exception {
    if (genericConfig instanceof JettyServerConfiguration) {
        configuration = (JettyServerConfiguration) genericConfig;
    } else {
        configuration = XmlConfigurable.createInstance(JettyServerConfiguration.class,
                genericConfig.getXmlConfigElement());
    }

    server = new Server();
    log.info("jetty version = " + Server.getVersion()); //frozen

    maxWaitForSlave = getConfiguration().getMaxWaitForSlave();

    final boolean debug = getConfiguration().getMortBayDebug();
    log.info("mortbay debug = '" + debug + "'"); //frozen
    //org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLog().setDebugEnabled(debug);


        //Re-writing code for Jetty 9.3
        final int mainPort = getConfiguration().getHttpPort();//8580
        final int sslPort = getConfiguration().getSslPort(); //8581
        final String sslKeyStore = getConfiguration().getSslKeyStore();
        final String sslPassword = getConfiguration().getSslPassword();
        final String sslKeyPassword = getConfiguration().getSslKeyPassword();
        final String sslTrustPassword = getConfiguration().getSslTrustPassword();
        //Added for  Jetty 9.3
        final KeyStore trustKeyStore=KeyStore.getInstance(getConfiguration().getSslKeyStore());

        ClassLoader cl = JettyServer.class.getClassLoader();// Get the class loader for my current class which is JettyServer
        String keystoreResource = "ssl/keystore";
         URL f = cl.getResource(keystoreResource);

         if (f == null)
         {
             throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find " + keystoreResource);
         }

         // Setup HTTP Connector
         HttpConfiguration httpConf = new HttpConfiguration();
         httpConf.setSecurePort(mainPort);
         httpConf.setSecureScheme("https");

         // Establish the HTTP ServerConnector
         ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
                 new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConf));
         httpConnector.setPort(mainPort);
         server.addConnector(httpConnector);

         // Setup SSL
        SslContextFactory theSSLFactory = new SslContextFactory();

        theSSLFactory.setKeyStorePath(f.toExternalForm());  //replaced for--> theSSLFactory.setKeyStorePath(sslKeyStore);
        theSSLFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(sslPassword);  // or this one ? seems hardcoded --> sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g");
        theSSLFactory.setKeyStorePassword(sslKeyPassword); // or this one ? seems hardcoded --> sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4");
        theSSLFactory.setTrustStore(trustKeyStore);
        theSSLFactory.setTrustStorePassword(sslTrustPassword);

        // Setup HTTPS Configuration
        HttpConfiguration httpsConf = new HttpConfiguration(httpConf);
        httpsConf.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer()); // adds ssl info to request object

     // Establish the HTTPS ServerConnector
        ServerConnector httpsConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
                new SslConnectionFactory(theSSLFactory,"http/1.1"),
                new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConf));
        httpsConnector.setPort(sslPort);

        log.info("adding ssl connector on port '" + sslPort + "'"); //frozen
        server.addConnector(httpsConnector);



    // Check we had 1 connector else the server is useless
    if (server.getConnectors().length == 0) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("No connectors registered.  Please see HttpEnable or SslEnable XML tags."); //frozen
    }

    // Configure the handlers
    final HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();

    for (final WebAppContext webAppContext : getConfiguration().getWebAppContexts()) {
        log.info("Adding WebAppContext " + webAppContext.getWar() + " at " + webAppContext.getContextPath()); //frozen
        handlers.addHandler(webAppContext);
    }

    // See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Logging+Requests
    final boolean accessLogEnabled = getConfiguration().getLogEnabled();

    if (accessLogEnabled) {
        final RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
        final File logDir = ServiceUtilities.getLogDirectory();

        if (!logDir.exists()) {
            logDir.mkdirs();
        }

        final File logFile = new File(getConfiguration().getLogFormat());

        if (!logFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
            logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        final NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog(getConfiguration().getLogFormat());
        requestLog.setRetainDays(getConfiguration().getLogRetain());
        requestLog.setAppend(getConfiguration().getLogAppend());
        requestLog.setExtended(getConfiguration().getLogExtended());
        requestLog.setLogTimeZone(getConfiguration().getLogTz());
        requestLog.setLogLatency(getConfiguration().getLogLatency());
        requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
        handlers.addHandler(requestLogHandler);
    }

    handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());

    server.setHandler(handlers);

    server.setUserRealms(new UserRealm[] { new OSMUserRealm() });

    JettyServerInfo.install(server);

    super.initialize(configuration, controller, serviceId, lock);
}
```

> Still I am not sure what to do with this line.

server.setUserRealms(new UserRealm[] { new OSMUserRealm() });

> I didn't find any alternative method in jetty 9.3 for UserRealm, any
>   suggestion how can I re-write this line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reminder: Jetty versioning (since 1995) is `<servlet_support>.<major_version>.<minor_version>`

Congrats, you've essentially just skipped 14 major versions ahead in Jetty. :-)

No wonder it seems so daunting.

> decided to move to JAVA 8

Know that [January 2019 is the last day of Java 8 public updates](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html).
It's practically end of life at that point for non-paying oracle customers.

Note: Java 9 is already deprecated / unsupported.

Since you mention using SSL/TLS, its is **mandatory to keep your JVM up to date and [not use an expired JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u172-relnotes-4308893.html)** (Browser requirements and TLS requirements).

Consider upgrading (again) to Java 11 before this year (2018) is over.

The update cycle for java is accelerating, don't expect Java versions to stick around for years anymore.  Major versions are not expected to last more then 6 months (currently).

> log.info("mortbay debug = '" + debug + "'"); //frozen
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLog().setDebugEnabled(debug);

Logging doesn't work like this.

It depends on the implementation chosen (there's SLf4j, java.util.logging, and System.err now).   Using `Log.getLog()` gets you the root logging facade, and using `setDebugEnabled()` on the facade is just setting debug on the facade, not the actual loggers.

Use a proper logging implementation and named loggers.

> if (nio) {
>                  connector = new SelectChannelConnector(server);
>              } else {
>                  connector = new SocketConnector(server);
>              }

There's no blocking connectors anymore, its 100% NIO based (for the past 5 major versions)

Welcome to the world of modern web protocols.

Gone are the days of a connector serving just 1 protocol, now its all negotiated during the actual connection.

Eg: Connect, TLS, ALPN, HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1 with TLS, HTTP/1.1 without TLS, etc. (And all of the information carried in the TLS negotiation of a single connection is also used to determine which webapp you talk to, using what host, and what certificates, etc)

A ServerConnector's role is to only listen to a port, the ConnectionFactories you assign to the ServerConnector determine what to do with that connection.

Read the various example code for this.

See:

- [eclipse/jetty.project/examples/embedded](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded)
- [jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook)
- [eclipse/jetty.project/examples/embedded - LikeJettyXml.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/LikeJettyXml.java)
- [eclipse/jetty.project/examples/embedded - Http2Server.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/Http2Server.java)

A simplified example:

```java
    Server server = new Server();
    int httpsPort = 8443;

    // Find Keystore
    ClassLoader cl = ServerConnectorHttps.class.getClassLoader();
    String keystoreResource = "ssl/keystore";
    URL f = cl.getResource(keystoreResource);
    if (f == null)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find " + keystoreResource);
    }

    // Setup SSL
    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(f.toExternalForm());
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g");

    // Setup HTTPS Configuration
    HttpConfiguration httpsConf = new HttpConfiguration();
    httpsConf.setSecurePort(httpsPort);
    httpsConf.setSecureScheme("https");
    httpsConf.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer()); // adds ssl info to request object

    // Establish the ServerConnector
    ServerConnector httpsConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,"http/1.1"),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConf));
    httpsConnector.setPort(httpsPort);

    server.addConnector(httpsConnector);

    // Add a Handler for requests
    server.setHandler(new HelloHandler("Hello Secure World"));

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

> server.setUserRealms(new UserRealm[] { new OSMUserRealm() });
>   I didn't find any alternative method in jetty 9.3 for UserRealm, any suggestion how can I re-write this line of code?

Security is handled by the LoginService, a LoginService could hold a realm (if that LoginService supports such a concept).

A LoginService can belong as a Bean on the server, but that's only for controlling the LifeCycle of the LoginService.

A WebAppContext with a security context setup to use a specific realm will find all LoginService beans on the server and use the one that matches the Realm specified.

Comment: If I understood you properly, I should re-write the code in line with the one you suggested in example and I can scrap the older code without any problem. In that case can I continue using the keyStoreptah,keyStorePassword,keyManagerPassword as earlier or I can use your suggested way, I guess the values are hardcoded? How about the userRealm part do I need to take care of it in the latest jetty. Any suggestion or example to handle realm in this case/

Comment: I have modified the code. Can you have a look and suggest if anything is missing or wrong.

Comment: Also not sure what is the use of String keystoreResource = "ssl/keystore"; and is it applied correctly in my code as I am not clear in this part. How do cl.getResource(keystoreResource); returns any value?

Comment: Do you think the following line should be changed as well?

Comment: Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList
                .setServerDefault( server );
        classlist.addBefore(
                "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
                "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration" );
   
    webAppContext.setAttribute(
                "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
                ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$" );
   
            handlers.addHandler(webAppContext);

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for having an ongoing conversation like this.  Either ask new / different questions, or use the jetty-users mailing list.

Comment: Judging by the types of questions you are asking, use the jetty-users mailing list. You'll find many individuals that have already gone through the effort you are doing now.