# org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector Missing in new Eclipse Jetty Jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am in the process of upgrading all the JARs for my application. The previous version of eclipse.jetty JARs that I used was 7.6.10. Which had the class mentioned. So, now that I am upgrading to 9.4.14.v20181114, I don't see any of the JAR files having this package at all. Can you tell me if the package was totally dropped or moved to some other JAR that I have no idea about. If the classes are gone, some pointers on how to rework the code would be helpful as well.

Comment: Previously answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794148/775715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered before at:

- [SelectChannelConnector alternative class in Jetty 9 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794148/775715)
- [Upgrading Jetty 8 to Jetty 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48749182/775715)
- [Migrating Jetty 6.1 to 9.3 has multiple issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50819405/775715)

Since you didn't detail what exactly your goal is, I cannot give you a targeted answer.

In short, you will be using the `ServerConnector` and appropriate configuration for it to accomplish whatever end goal you have.

See examples above in prior answers, and also the various embedded-jetty examples available by the Eclipse Jetty project itself.

- https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook
- https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the info. That is enough for me to get started.